# International law: Could this kik sexting interaction bring legal trouble?

Tags: international

One of my friends is freaking out completely over this. Right off the bat, yes its stupid and this was her first time, she wasnt thinking.

So, my bi friend( lets call her liv) who is 20, found a girl on omegle who said she is 25. They started talking on kik and Liv sent some explicit photos and videos. When she asked the other girl to send something, she did, but then later Liv realizes that those photos are actually screenshots and the pictures arent of the person she is speaking to. She asked her about it and the person bolted. Stopped replying to her texts. Ghosted her for a week. Liv finally deactivated her account permanently. Now her worst worry is that this other person is much younger or something. They are also from different countries( continents) . Liv is from India. The other person is from Missouri, USA. So,
 1) could Liv get into legal trouble if the person is, say young? To what extent is it likely to go? ( The other person said she was 25. Nowhere did she say any other age. And she did not send pics of herself. The ones she sent were screenshots of pics of someone else)

Comment: What is [Catfishing?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catfishing) for the win!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the other girl was a fat bloke in his forties, so Liv hasn't done anything illegal as far as the age of the other person is concerned. In some places sending explicit photos of yourself as a twenty year old woman to another adult person may be illegal, but since she's not worried about that, I assume it's not.

There is of course the very real danger that her photos and videos get distributed. So if she doesn't like the idea of any random person seeing these photos and videos, that's too late now. However, unless she also gave information about her address, then these photos are unlikely to be seen by anyone she knows. And there is so much stuff on the internet, that it is unlikely anyone would recognise her.

For any legal danger, the other person would have to be underage (not very likely), someone would have to find out who and where she is, and then somebody would have to be willing to spend the time and money to prosecute someone in India from Missouri. I don't think the police in Missouri would be bothered to even try, because the chances of succesful conviction would be very slim compared to the cost. They frankly have more important things to do.

Comment: Thank you so much. Thats actually very helpful. And ,her face werent in the pics and no distinct identifiable features. And she did not give out her address.